# Turn LED notification light on when the front camera is being used by any app

Tags: notifications, tasker, automation, notification-led, front-camera

I am looking for an app, or profiles in Tasker which would turn on the LED notification light for supporting phones, whenever the front camera is accessed by an app. Many laptops have similar features.

Comment: @beeshyams My aim is indeed that but locking and unlocking for each snap is too much work.

Comment: @beeshyams Can you please give me the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62511/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-reeshabh-ranjan).